# Не работает proxy_pass внутри pod на внутренний сервис в Kubernetes, connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, pod

Всем добрый день!
Все это делается на Kubernetes на AWS (EKS)

Пытаюсь запустить nginx proxy в контейнере которые будет перекидывать на внутренний сервис.
Схема следующая:

alb ingress controller -> service nginx -> nginx pod -> my service -> myservice pod

Ошибка в error.log nginx pod:

```
2019/04/10 06:07:31 [error] 6#6: *116 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.43.108, server: myservice.host.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.31.9.18:80/", host: "172.31.8.88"
```

Вот так, все работает:
alb ingress controller -> my service -> myservice pod

INGRESS делал вот по этой статье, он работает нормально:
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/walkthrough/echoserver/

Мои конфиги:

---

myservice-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservice-ingress
  namespace: myservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-xxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80}]'
 spec:
   rules:
     - host: myservice.host.com
       http:
         paths:
           - path: /*
             backend:
               serviceName: nginx-svc
               servicePort: 80
```

---

myservice-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: myservice
  name: myservice-svc
  #name: nginx-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: myservice
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myservice
    stack: master
  clusterIP: None
```

---

nginx-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
  namespace: myservice
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myservice-nginx
  clusterIP: None
```

---

nginx-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice-nginx
  namespace: myservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: cshlovjah/nginx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: myservice-nginx
          ports:
          - name: liveness-port
            containerPort: 80
            hostPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
          - name: nginx-config
            mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            readOnly: true
            subPath: default.conf
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: myservice-config
            items:
            - key: default
            path: default.conf
```

---

default.conf:

```
upstream myservice_service {
     server myservice-svc;
     keepalive 64;
}

server {
listen       80;
server_name  myservice.host.com;

#location / {
#    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
#    index  index.html index.htm;
#}

location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_pass http://myservice_service;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
}

location /healtz {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  healtz.html healtz.htm;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

access_log /var/log/nginx/access_myservice.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error_myservice.log;
}
```

---

myservice-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: myservice
  name: myservice
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myservice
      stack: master
strategy:
  type: Recreate
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: myservice
      stack: master
  spec:
    containers:
    - image: cshlovjah/kubia
      name: myservice
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
        name: myservice
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Все проблема снята! 
В endpoints посмотрел:

```
$ kubectl get endpoints -n myservice
NAME            ENDPOINTS          AGE
myservice-svc   172.31.9.18:8080   100m
nginx-svc       172.31.45.33:80    102m
```

---

в default.conf:

```
upstream myservice_service {
     server myservice-svc:8080;
     keepalive 64;
}
```